# Why do Stack Exchange websites use a vanilla JavaScript confirm button?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

Stack Overflow and other websites of the network are using the JavaScript confirm button, as of

```
if (confirm("Really delete this comment?"))
   //Delete comment code
```

[image: The confirm dialog button]

I even found this script:

```
<div id="show-editor-button" class="form-submit">
    <input type="button"
           value="Add Another Answer"
           data-confirm-text="Are you sure you want to add another answer?

You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead."
           data-confirm-use-fancy="False"
           data-confirm-fancy-title=""
           data-confirm-fancy-body=""
           data-confirm-fancy-accept-button=""/>
</div>
<script>
    StackExchange.ready(function () {
        $("#show-editor-button input").click(function () {
            var showEditor = function() {
                $("#show-editor-button").hide();
                $("#post-form").removeClass("dno");
                StackExchange.editor.finallyInit();
            };

            var useFancy = $(this).data('confirm-use-fancy');
            if(useFancy == 'True') {
                var popupTitle = $(this).data('confirm-fancy-title');
                var popupBody = $(this).data('confirm-fancy-body');
                var popupAccept = $(this).data('confirm-fancy-accept-button');

                $(this).loadPopup({
                    url: '/post/self-answer-popup',
                    loaded: function(popup) {
                        var pTitle = $(popup).find('h2');
                        var pBody = $(popup).find('.popup-body');
                        var pSubmit = $(popup).find('.popup-submit');

                        pTitle.text(popupTitle);
                        pBody.html(popupBody);
                        pSubmit.val(popupAccept).click(showEditor);
                    }
                })
            } else{
                var confirmText = $(this).data('confirm-text');
                if (confirmText ? confirm(confirmText) : true) {
                    showEditor();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It looks like they have markup for a "fancier" confirm button. Why not use it?

I know it's just a user experience-related question, but there are many cool dialog plugins out there, like SweetAlert 2, etc.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the standard confirmation dialog? Why SE needs fancy colors? It's for professionals, so better stick to useful design.

Comment: Why not use the default button instead of the blue "Add Comment button" by the side of this box I'm typing in? The confirm button looks ok on chrome, not so much on IE, it's just a UX related question, as I said.

Answer (score 7):

I think the current design is better than all those custom confirm dialogs. Wasn't the browser dialog created for this purpose?

It is very hard to make a dialog that works on all devices, so the one the browser uses is most likely the one that fits best. I think it is better to rely on already existing dialogs rather than reinvent the wheel.

And indeed, they use some custom dialogs, for example when closing a question, but they rather don't if they don't have to.

Comment: Hmm, yeah the compatibility issue is dangerous.

Comment: I actually don't mind the confirm button, it's just something I was wondering why it is like that. But for me it makes it look kind like a inconsistency, since the entire website is pretty, but they use default confirm dialog.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes the default Safari confirmation dialog is actually quite pretty and not out-of-place in the Stack Exchange design.

Comment: SE already *does* rely on custom dialogs for many far more important things than comment deletion, comment vote undoing, and reopening. Compatibility is a red herring.

Comment: @nat indeed. They use custom dialogs. One that isn't working too well is the close dialog on mobile. It is very hard to fix that because of all the different devices and form factors.

Comment: They have the custom dialog for closing questions, for example. They could use the same layout for a confirmation box.

Comment: Because that dialog sucks, especially on mobile. And it is not just a yes/no dialog. It has a search bar, results list, etc. @phi